# How to code CSS in eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse, helios

Is there anyway I can develop CSS in eclipse. Im using Eclipse Helios version and I want to be able to create CSS pages in it. But I couldnt find CSS file anywhere in it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to install the Web tools for Eclipse. This means: choose the Eclipse Enterprise installation or add the WTP project in your existing Eclipse instance. For the latter, go to Help -> Install new software, select the Eclipse update site and then choose the WTP project to be added.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is a really old post, but for the benefit of others who get here looking for CSS support in Eclipse, I would encourage you to give CodeMix a try for a truly superlative experience.

Key features:

- Supports all the CSS 3 properties, including support for variables
- In-built Emmet integration reduces typing required
- Includes a CSS validator
- Sass and LESS supported too

For more, see: https://www.genuitec.com/tech/css3-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

In the menu file -> new -> other and as type CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can always instal Aptana Studio ( 3 beta ) plugin for your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

File > New > File
Write the name of your file with the .css extension.

To have colors and a friendly visual I think if you don't have support will need download any plugin. 
I usually use this and it's good 
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-tools-lightweight-css-editor